# Latex Beamer: draw arrow and text on resized tikzpicture but text should have same font as presentation

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-node, resize

I make a presentation and there I have a `tikzpicture` scaled with `resizebox`.

I now want to draw an error to a `tikzmark`, but the node text at the arrow should have the same font size as the rest of the presentation, not as the text in the tikzfigure.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetheme{Madrid}

% tikz
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,positioning}

% Mathematical stuff
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\mathbf{\boldsymbol{#1}}} % bold vectors which also support greek letters
\newcommand{\mat}[1]{\mathbf{\boldsymbol{#1}}}  % bold matrices
\newcommand*{\tran}{^{\mkern-1.5mu\mathsf{T}}}

% for brackets: [[ ]]
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\begin{document}
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

    \tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

    \begin{frame}{Matrix Decomposition}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tikzpicture}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{1.5}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{1.5}

            % X
            \draw (0,0) node (start) {} --  ++(\cubex,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey) -- node[midway,above = 0.3*\cubey] {$\mat{X}$} node[midway,below] {data}++(-\cubex,0) -- cycle;

            \path (start) ++ (1.5*\cubex,-0.5*\cubey) node (approx) {$\approx$};

            % X_hat
            \draw (approx) ++ (0.5*\cubex,0.5*\cubey) node (lowrank) {} -- ++(\cubex,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey) -- node[midway,above = 0.3*\cubey] {$\mat{\hat{X}}$} node[midway,below] {low-rank model} ++(-\cubex,0) -- cycle;

            \path (lowrank) ++ (1.5*\cubex,-0.5*\cubey) node (equal) {=};

            % a_1, b_1
            \draw (equal) ++ (0.5*\cubex,0.5*\cubey-0.1*\cubey) node (1) {} -- ++(0.1*\cubex,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey)-- node[midway,below] {$\vect{a}_1$} ++(-0.1*\cubex,0) -- cycle;
            \draw (equal) ++ (0.5*\cubex+0.2*\cubex,0.5*\cubey) -- ++(\cubex,0) -- node[midway,right] {$\vect{b}_1$} ++(0,0.1*\cubey) -- ++(-\cubex,0) -- cycle;

            % red box
            \draw[rounded corners,red,thick] (1) ++ (-0.2*\cubex, 0.4*\cubey) -- ++(1.8*\cubex,0) -- ++(0,-1.8*\cubey) -- node (comp) {} ++(-1.8*\cubex,0) -- cycle;

            %% I could use these two lines, but then the font size is as the other letters in the tikzpicture, but different from the slides font size
            %\path (comp) ++ (2*\cubex,-\cubey) node[text=red] (comptext) {Component};
            %\path[->] (comptext.west) edge [ultra thick, red, bend left] (comp);

            \path (1) ++ (2*\cubex,-0.5*\cubey+0.1*\cubey) node (p2) {+};
            \path (p2) ++ (0.5*\cubex,0) node (dots) {\dots};
            \path (dots) ++ (0.5*\cubex,0) node (p3) {+};

            %a_R, b_R
            \draw (p3) ++ (0.5*\cubex,0.5*\cubey-0.1*\cubey) node (3) {} -- ++(0.1*\cubex,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey) -- node[midway,below] {$\vect{a}_R$} ++(-0.1*\cubex,0) -- cycle;
            \draw (p3) ++ (0.5*\cubex+0.2*\cubex,0.5*\cubey) -- ++(\cubex,0) -- node[midway,right] {$\vect{b}_R$} ++(0,0.1*\cubey) -- ++(-\cubex,0) -- cycle;

            \path (3) ++ (2*\cubex,-0.5*\cubey) node (equal2) {=};

            % A B.T
            \draw (equal2) ++ (0.5*\cubex,0.5*\cubey) node (A) {} --  ++(0.5*\cubex,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey) -- node[midway,above = 0.3*\cubey] {$\mat{A}$} ++(-0.5*\cubex,0) -- cycle;
            \path (A) ++ (0.5*\cubex,-0.5*\cubey) node (times) {};
            \draw (times) ++ (0.1*\cubex,0.5*\cubey) node (B) {} --  ++(\cubex,0) -- ++(0,-0.5*\cubey) -- node[midway,above = 0.05*\cubey] {$\mat{B}\tran$} ++(-\cubex,0) -- cycle;

            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    \end{figure}

    %% when using these two lines, the label is wrong positioned
    %\tikz[overlay] {\path (comp) ++ (1,-1) node[text=red] (comptext) {Component};}
    %\tikz[overlay] {\path[->] (comptext.west) edge [ultra thick, red, bend left] (comp);}

    \begin{align*}
    \mat{X} \approx \mat{\hat{X}} = \sum_{r=1}^{R} \vect{a}_r \circ \vect{b}_r = \mat{A} \mat{B}\tran = \llbracket \mat{A}, \mat{B} \rrbracket
    \end{align*}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

As written in the comments in the code, I have found two possibilities:

1. draw the arrow and text in the `tikzpicture`, but then the font size is smaller than the other text on the slides (two commented lines in the tikzpicture)

[image]

2. draw the arrow and text outside the `tikzpicture`, font size is fine now but the arrow points to the wrong position (two commented lines outside of the `\tikzpicture`).

[image]

I would prefer the solution on how to fix the 2nd problems, but I am happy also with a solution for the first problem.

Comment: Instead of `\tikz[overlay] ...` try `\tikz[overlay,remember picture] ...` in the commented out part. BTW, `\tikzstyle` is deprecated. OK, you add `\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]`, so the issue is that you resize the picture from outside. Instead of `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tikzpicture}` use `begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,transform shape]`. `0.6` is just a guess.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this has worked! Would you like to write it as answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: In my other tikzpicture, I have a three-dimensional plot closed with cycle, and this is destroyed by adding scale=0.6,transform shape. Do you know if there are conflicts with scale and cycle?

Comment: Did you run it twice after changing the scale?  The origin may have moved.

Comment: Hmm, I do not know your plot example. However, if this is pgfplots, you need to add the `[scale=0.6,transform shape]` after `\begin{axis}` and not after `\begin{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Yes I ran it several times.
@Schrödinger'scat I dont' have `\begin{axis}` in the picture. Is it nearly the same as above, but instead of two squares, I have two cubes:
`\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{1.5}`
`\draw (0,0,0) node (start) {} -- node[midway,above,text=gray] {$J$} ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- node[midway,left,text=gray] {$I$} ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- node[midway,above = 0.3*\cubey] {$\ten{X}$} ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle`
`-- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle`
`-- node[midway,below,text=gray] {$K$} ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- cycle;`

Comment: The first looks fine, the second cube not.

Comment: Isi, is this question still open, I can't figure by the comments if your problem was solved or not

Comment: Hi BambOo! My original question was solved already by the first comment, that's why I asked to write it as answer :) I made the slide different so I didn't need it in a 3D cube